# Using custom data types in jooq's condition expression

Tags: java, postgis, jooq

I am using jooq with a custom binding that converts all JTS geometry types to appropriate Postgis data types. This allows me to write and read JTS geometry types seamlessly, yet I fail to execute queries using those same custom types.

For example when I am trying to add this condition to a query:

```java
Polygon polygon = geometryFactory.createPolygon(
  new Coordinate[]{topLeftCorner, bottomLeftCorner, bottomRightCorner, topRightCorner, topLeftCorner}
);
polygon.setSRID(4326);
DSL.condition("ST_WITHIN({0}, {1})", USER.COORDINATES, polygon)
```

it fails with the following message

```
org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon is not supported in dialect DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using jOOQ 3.16

Starting with jOOQ 3.16, [#982](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/982) has been implemented and jOOQ supports [ISO/IEC 13249-3:2016](https://www.iso.org/standard/60343.html) spatial extensions out of the box. Your generated code will reference the `SQLDataType.GEOMETRY` type, for example, and you can use WKT or WKB encodeded spatial data in `org.jooq.Geometry`, the wrapper type, just like any other data type in jOOQ.

[A lot of spatial functions are already supported out of the box](https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/spatial-functions/). If something is still missing, you can always resort to using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/).

#### Using older jOOQ versions

You need to create a [custom data type binding](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/) for your various GIS types, and then either [attach that to your generated code](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/) (e.g. to the `ST_WITHIN` stored function), or create auxiliary library methods that use the binding as follows:

```java
DataType<Polygon> polygonType = SQLDataType.OTHER.asConvertedDataType(binding);
Field<Polygon> bindValue = DSL.val(polygon, polygonType);
DSL.condition("ST_WITHIN({0}, {1})", USER.COORDINATES, bindValue);
```